# py2app IOError: [Errno 63] File name too long:

Tags: python, pyside, py2app

Im trying to package a PySide app with py2app on OS X 10.6 with python 2.6.

The problem i'm getting it that it seems like py2app is getting stuck in a loop and recursively appending the same directory path onto its self, and then it eventually hits the Python file too long IOError as above. Below is the stack trace I get

```
     copying /Users/mlakewood/Documents/Programming/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-
universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-
universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-
universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-
universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-
universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-
universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-
universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-
universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-
universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-
universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/_builtinSuites/__init__.pyc -> /Users/mlakewood/Documents/Programming/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/_builtinSuites
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/py2app/build_app.py", line 579, in _run
        self.run_normal()
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/py2app/build_app.py", line 650, in run_normal
        self.create_binaries(py_files, pkgdirs, extensions, loader_files)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/py2app/build_app.py", line 718, in create_binaries
        self.copy_package_data(item, self.collect_dir)
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/py2app/build_app.py", line 809, in copy_package_data
        copy_tree(pth, os.path.join(target_dir, fname))
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/py2app/util.py", line 501, in copy_tree
        dry_run=dry_run, condition=condition))
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/py2app/util.py", line 501, in copy_tree
        dry_run=dry_run, condition=condition))
      File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/py2app/util.py", line 501, in copy_tree
        dry_run=dry_run, condition=condition))
```

snip... (lots of lines that are all the same as the one above and below)

unsnip...

```
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/py2app/util.py", line 501, in copy_tree
    dry_run=dry_run, condition=condition))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/py2app/util.py", line 501, in copy_tree
    dry_run=dry_run, condition=condition))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/py2app/util.py", line 501, in copy_tree
    dry_run=dry_run, condition=condition))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/Extras/lib/python/py2app/util.py", line 504, in copy_tree
    preserve_times, update, dry_run=dry_run)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/file_util.py", line 165, in copy_file
    _copy_file_contents(src, dst)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/file_util.py", line 47, in _copy_file_contents
    fdst = open(dst, 'wb')
IOError: [Errno 63] File name too long: '/Users/mlakewood/Documents/Programming/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect/_builtinSuites/__init__.pyc'
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/file_util.py(47)_copy_file_contents()
-> fdst = open(dst, 'wb')
```

and below is my setup.py file

```
"""
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

Usage:
    python setup.py py2app
"""

from setuptools import setup

APP = ['gui.py']
DATA_FILES = []
OPTIONS = {}
#OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
    includes=['PySide']
)
```

Answer (score 11):

This question is really old, but I ran into the same problem last night and found a solution. Turned out for me that the problem was a byproduct of **py2app** trying to generate the *build* and *dis*t folders inside of another folder that contained modules referenced by the code being built.

Since **py2app** defaults to placing the *build* and *dist* folders in the current working directory, that means you're in trouble if you're writing a build script in the same working directory as other modules being referenced by your code.

I fixed the problem by using **py2app** options to force the *build* and *dist* directories to be created in the parent of the current directory below, but you could put them wherever you choose and achieve the same thing:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import py2app
import sys
from distutils.core import setup
from os import getcwd
from pathlib import Path

sys.argv.append('py2app')
setup(app=['<your_code.py>'],
      options=dict(py2app=dict(bdist_base=str(Path(getcwd()).parent)
      + '/build', dist_dir=str(Path(getcwd()).parent) + '/dist')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if the path has any symlinks that might cause infinite recursion.  Open up Terminal app, and type this:

```
ls -l /Users/mlakewood/Documents/Programming/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect
```

If you see something like this after doing the `ls -l`:

```
/Users/mlakewood/Documents/Programming/DataWrangler/build/bdist.macosx-10.6-universal/python2.6-standalone/app/collect -> ../../../../../build/
```

Then thats what is causing the issue.  But there definately is something causing an infinite recursive loop in the way the script is searching for the file.

Comment: hmm... before the build there arent any files in there. after the build fails, there arent any sim links in that folder.. so I dont *think* thats the issue... thanks for the answer tho..